# Is the link function in Probit model canonical?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model, probit, link-function

If I understand correctly, [Probit model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model) is a generalized linear model. I didn't see it listed in [the table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function), so I was wondering if its link function is canonical for some distribution?

Comment: In GLM terms probit defines a link; the most natural distribution family for that link is the binomial.

Comment: @NickCox: Thanks! The link corresponding to the binomial is logistic function, and the regression is logistic regression, not probit regression?

Comment: Say rather that the binomial and the logit hang together, but other links make sense for the binomial too. See e.g. http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rglm.pdf Table on p.7.

Comment: @NickCox: So the link function in Probit is not canonical?

Comment: Correct, I believe. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40876/difference-between-link-function-and-canonical-link-function-for-glm

Comment: I had some fun with this just trying to simplify the implied variance function assuming there were some exponential family distribution for which the probit link would be natural/canonical.

Answer (score 5):

As answered in comments, the canonical link function in the binomial model is the logit. So the probit link is **not** canonical.

That should not stop you from using it, however.  A link function being canonical is a purely mathematical concept without much statistical impact.  You should use the link function which are appropriate for the context you are modelling.   I  once had extensive bioassay data (goal was to model LD50) where it was actually possible to see that the probit link fitted the data (marginally) better than the logit link.  The difference was not large enough to have any practical significance, though.  Probably the difference came from the probit "kissing" its asymptotes much faster than the logit, which is natural for some bioassay data.  Simply, when the dose gets too high, all the animals die!