# Logistic Regression Vs Simple Regression

Tags: regression, interpretation, logit

I am new to this area of regression analysis

why do we select 
${e^{\beta x } }/{[1+e^{ \beta x}]}$  as $p\{Y=1|X\}$

or how to get $E(y |x )$ in the case where $y$ is dichotomous.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between linear regression and logistic regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29325/17230).

Comment: No but that answer is not satisfying me

Comment: @ Scortchi kindly see the question again

Comment: See [Problem understanding the logistic regression link function](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/80611/17230); also [Difference between logit and probit models](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20523/17230), & [Is the logit function always the best for regression modeling of binary data?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48072/17230). Not sure what you mean by "how to get $\operatorname{E} (Y\mid x)$" - performing logistic regression is a way to estimate it. Or are you asking why $\operatorname{E} (Y\mid x) = \Pr(Y=1 \mid x)$?