Why residual term $\epsilon$ is not included in logistic regression specification?
I have a simple question, which bothers me. In the logistic regression context, the odds are defined as:
$$\frac{p(X)}{1-p(X)} = e^{\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X}.$$
I was wondering, why in the literature the residual term $\epsilon$ is never included in the exponent?

Welcome to Cross Validated! I believe the linked question and answers address this quite well. If they do not, please say what remains confusing for you.

here is another link that more explicitly talks about logit, vs GLM: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481391/why-do-we-model-noise-in-linear-regression-but-not-logistic-regression

...and another that shows that the error can be thought of existing in an underlying latent regression that leads to this "odds" expression, which then it is no longer "defined" but derived. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/80623/28746
