# Fixed effect Logit with R

Tags: r, econometrics, logit, fixed-effects-model

I would like to perform a Fixed effect logit estimation in R. 
Can someone point out a package that can do the job?

Note: For the time being I'm not really interested in the random effect.

Update;

Essentially I wonder if there is the plm package for a binary response model.

Here is some documentation for the plm package:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/index.html 
http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.pdf

Comment: It might help to post the `head()` of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new R Package called "bife" that performs Fixed Effects binary logit Models.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bife/vignettes/howto.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/118559)

Comment: Sycorax, in general you're right, but the question was "Can someone point out a package that can do the job?". Therefore, I don't see why my answer doesn't include "the essential parts of the answer here".

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think the package is best for FE logit model in R. However, I want to include lags of dependent & independent variables in logit regression of daily time series dataset. Is there any package for it?

Comment: looks like the link changed... :D

Comment: @Mumbo.Jumbo Did you find an R package that makes it easy to include lags in a longitudinal dataset for logistic regression?

Comment: link is broken. I updated it

Comment: Be careful to those reading this as the correct answer and read the other answers below. The bife package performs the demeaned/dummy variable version of fixed effects but using a logistic function. This is not quite analogous to how this operation works for a linear model and the math breaks down (see generic_user's answer below). As Glen_b says below, usually when economists etc refer to "logistic model with fixed effects" they are referring to a conditional logistic regression as in the xtlogit command in STATA. the clogit command in the survival package is closer.

Answer (score 10):

If you mean logistic regression, for example, along the lines of

$Y_i\sim\text{Bernoulli}(1,p_i)\,$, with

$\text{logit}(p_i) = X\beta\,$,

(equivalently, $P[Y_i=1] = \frac{\exp(X\beta)}{1+\exp(X\beta)},$)

then use `glm`. For example:

```
glm(y~x1+x2,family=binomial)
```

There are examples in the help at `?glm.predict`, `?infert` and `?esoph`.

If you mean fitting a logistic curve via least squares, like

$E(Y) = \alpha \cdot(\frac{\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x)}{1+\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x)})$

then use `nls`. There's an example of fitting a logistic function in the help at `?nls`.

Both are part of the standard R installation.

If you mean something else, you need to clarify what you want.

---

I see from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40879/805) that apparently economists use 'fixed effect model' to refer to a conditional logit model, even though it's far from the only fixed effect model involving a logit. Who would have thought.

As ndoogan mentions in one of the other answers, there's a conditional logistic regression model (`clogit`) in the `survival` package.

Answer (score 8):

I'm almost certain that you mean conditional logistic regression. This will estimate the within-group relationship between your independent variables and your binary dependent variable. It's similar to adding a dummy for each individual (as in fixed effects). In which case, use the `clogit()` function in the `survival` package that is included with R.

Answer (score 5):

Standard fixed effects assumptions break down in nonlinear models (like logit).

When you can assume gaussian disturbance, you can model:
$$
y_{it} = X_{it}\beta + u_{it}\\
y_{it} = X_{it}\beta + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it}\\
y_{it} - \bar{y}_i = (X_{it}-\bar{X}_i) \beta + \alpha_i - \bar\alpha_i + \epsilon_{it} -\bar\epsilon_i\\
y_{it}^{dm}  = X_{it}^{dm} \beta + \epsilon_{it}^{dm}
$$
where $dm$ is the deviation from the mean.  This is the within transformation.  You get rid of all of your time-invariant heterogeneity, and if you can make an argument that $E[\epsilon_{it}|X,\alpha]=0$, then $\beta$ gets a causal interpretation.

Try this math with a logit link functions and you'll see that it all breaks down.  Other approaches exist -- one of the other answerers suggested conditional logit.

Comment: This is true but hardly comes close to answering the question.