# What is the canonical link function for a multinomial logit?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution, link-function, multinomial-logit

For the [multinomial logit model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression), what is the canonical link function and how does it relate to the definition of the canonical link as defined in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40880/)?

I note from [this link on glms](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/216), Agresti calls the link the generalised logit, but unfortunately I don't have the book.