# What's the intuition behind the canonical link function in GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, intuition, exponential-family

I have already read the answer from [What is the difference between a “link function” and a “canonical link function” for GLM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40876/what-is-the-difference-between-a-link-function-and-a-canonical-link-function) but I think my question is different from this one. I am watching the [MIT open course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYcdw5vOgIc) on GLM and the explanation of the link function is wonderful and crystal clear. What I am still confused about is why the canonical link function, **canonical to** the particular distribution of the canonical exponential family is defined as the inverse of $b'$?

The exponential family can always be written in the following form:
$$f_{\theta}(y)=\exp \left(\frac{y \theta-b(\theta)}{\phi}+c(y, \phi)\right)$$

In the lecture, the professor explains a **canonical link function** $g$ is canonical to the distribution which belongs to the canonical exponential family, and the canonical exponential family is completely characterized by $b$, hence we only need to know the **connection between** $g$ and $b$. Then the professor moves onto say $g=(b')^{-1}$

But just why the canonical link is connected to $b$ through the inverse of the first derivative of $b$ is unclear. Why not $g=b^{-1}$?

Besides, by defining $g=(b')^{-1}$, we are able to substitute $\theta$ by $X^T\beta$ when modeling, and it is much easier to solve the optimization problem of the log-likelihood. But that means the fact that link is called **canonical** is because it will result in the function which links $\theta$ and $X^T\beta$ being an identity. How does making the function between $\theta$ and $X^T\beta$ an identity has anything to do with the link being **canonical?** i.e. canonical in what sense?

Comment: Please correct the typo: $c(y,\phi) \mapsto c(\theta,\phi)$.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Hi, I think it is not a typo. $\phi$ is assumed to be known in the canonical exponential family form and it needs some function of $y$ to make sure the integral sums up to 1.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to distinguish the distribution part and the model part (also called structural part or something).

**The distribution part**. Consider a distribution of the form you presented. Note that not every exponential family distribution is of this form, but this form defines a proper sub-family of the exponential family. For any exp. fam. distribution the following relation holds: $E[s(y)]=b'(\theta)$, where $s(\cdot)$  is the sufficient statistic, $E$ denotes expectation, $b(\cdot)$ is the log-partition function, and $\theta$ is the natural/canonical parameter. For our distribution, we have $s(y)=y$, and although $\theta$ and $c(\theta)$ are not exactly the natural parameter and the partition function (but their scaled versions), we still have $E[y]=b'(\theta)$. This establishes the relation $E_\theta[y]=g^{-1}(\theta)$, where we have introduced an invertible function $g$. We don't give function $g$ any name at this point, we only note that it is determined by the distribution we chose.

**The model part**. Now we want to build a regression or classification model, in which we want to predict outputs $y(\boldsymbol{x})$ based on inputs $\boldsymbol{x}$. We decide that $y(\boldsymbol{x})$ is distributed with the pdf $f_\theta(y)$, which implicitly depends on $x$. We decide that this dependence should be such that $\mu(\boldsymbol{x}):=E[y(\boldsymbol{x})]=h(\boldsymbol{\beta}^T \boldsymbol{x})$, where $h$ is an invertible function of our choice and is called *mean function*; and its inverse $h^{-1}(\cdot)$ is called *link function*. To make the implicit dependence of $f_\theta(y)$ on $x$ explicit, we write $\theta(\boldsymbol{x}) = g(\mu(\boldsymbol{x})) = g(h(\boldsymbol{\beta}^T \boldsymbol{x}))$.

The pointwise dependence of $\theta$ on $\boldsymbol{x}$ is the simplest when $g\equiv h^{-1}$. To highlight this exceptional property, we call $h^{-1}$ *the canonical link function* (as opposed to just *a link function*). Oh! But then $g$ , which is the same function, can also be called *the canonical link function*.

**Update**. The above should remove the confusion you express in

> But just why the canonical link is connected to $b$ through the inverse of the first derivative of $b$ is unclear. Why not $g=b^{-1}$?

As to the word *canonical*, I think, it is not related to the "canonical form" or the "canonical parameter"; it is just the same word used in a different situation and in a different sense. You can replace the term "canonical link" with "organic link function". And among possible choices of the link function there will the "organic link function", which is *organic to* a given distribution, because it makes $\theta$ of this distribution equal $\boldsymbol{\beta}^T\boldsymbol{x}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Yes, you indeed answered my question of why the canonical link is $g^{-1}$. A minor question on your explanation, why do you change $b'$ into $g^{-1}$, aren't they supposed to mean the same thing?

Comment: @JoZ They are. I am simply following authors I read. I guess, the point of introducing this additional notation is to abstract from the details of the distribution and to take away only that there is a relation between $\theta$ and $\mu$. Also, $b'^{(-1)}$ does not look nice. You see different notation in different texts, but several books that I came across do that.

Comment: @paperskilltress Thank you so much for being patient. I am just personally easily get confused with a lot of inverses get involved in, but I think I get the idea from your answer!

Comment: The usual alternative term to "canonical link" would be "natural link" rather then "organic link"

Comment: @Glen_b I intentionally chose an unused adjective to demonstrate that it is a separate unrelated notion: "natural" is already used in "natural parameter" and "natural family". If you are saying that "natural link" is used interchangeably with "canonical link" (just as "natural parameter"="canonical parameter"), then thank you, it is good to know!